# I am trying to calculate VOE and VD but i got this type of error "TypeError: only size-1 arrays can be converted to Python scalars"

Tags: python

I have Python code:

```
import numpy as np
import SimpleITK as sitk

y_true = sitk.ReadImage("C:/Users/lenovo/Desktop/safa/driveknee/drive-download-20190515T061013Z-001/IBSR_13/IBSR_13_segTRI_ana.nii")

y_pred = sitk.ReadImage("C:/Users/lenovo/Desktop/safa/driveknee/drive-download-20190515T061013Z-001/IBSR_13/IBSR_13_segTRI_predict.nii")

print("img true")
print (y_true)
print("img predict")
print (y_pred)

t = np.array(y_true)
p = np.array(y_pred) 

print("img true_array")
print (t)
print("img predict_array")

print (p)

voe = 100 * (1. - np.logical_and(t, p).sum() / float(np.logical_or(t, p)))
vd = 100 * (t.sum() - p.sum()) / float(p.sum())

print("VOE" , voe)
print("VD" , vd)
```

And i got this error:

Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "VOE.py", line 24, in

voe = 100 * ((1. - np.logical_and(t, p).sum() / float(np.logical_or(t, p))))

TypeError: only size-1 arrays can be converted to Python scalars

How can I fix it?

Comment: provide those two download to reproduce the example

Comment: @geekzeus You mean you want to see the data I downloaded?

Answer (score 0):

y_true and y_pred are of type sitk.Image. You need to call sitk.GetArrayFromImage with them to create numpy arrays.

I'm surprised the assignments to 't' and p' worked. I don't know what happens when you try to construct a np.array with a sitk.Image.

Trying your code, the denominator of your expression to compute VOE is the problem.  np.logical_or is returning a numpy array.  You can't just cast that to float.

Comment: i tried sitk.GetArrayFromImage but still the same problem